# Grep command from json file - Bash scripting

Tags: json, bash

My json file has the below content:

```
{
  "Fruits": {
    "counter": 1,
    "protocols": [
      {
        "id": "100",
        "name": "lemon",
        "category": "citrus"
      },
      {
        "id": "350",
        "name": "Orange",
        "category": "citrus"
      },
      {
        "id": "150",
        "name": "lime",
        "category": "citrus"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I am expecting an output as below

```
Fruits:lemon:citrus
Fruits:Orange:citrus
Fruits:lime:citrus
```

Comment: Don't use `grep` to process JSON. Use `jq`

Answer (score 5):

Easy to do with `jq`:

```
$ jq -r '.Fruits.protocols[] | "Fruits:\(.name):\(.category)"' input.json
Fruits:lemon:citrus
Fruits:Orange:citrus
Fruits:lime:citrus
```

Comment: Nice!, I really like `jq` it becomes easy to parse `json` files using the shell.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately  jq cannot be installed in my production environment. Is there any other alternative?

Comment: @apoonkun What a pity, as the solution is very nice. If you have Ruby, you can try my answer. Maybe it helps you.

Comment: @apoonkun You could use perl or python also, but, really, trying to do shell scripting that manipulates JSON without using jq is a Bad Idea.

Comment: Even in `git-bash` you can install `jq` :-)

Answer (score 0):

The `jq` answer is better. Still posting a Ruby solution (if you cannot use jq), but it is less elegant:

```
ruby -e '
  require "json";
  l="";
  ARGF.each { |x| l+=x };
  obj=JSON.parse(l);
  obj["Fruits"]["protocols"].each { |x| puts "Fruits:#{x["name"]}:#{x["category"]}" }
'
```

Here is the full example:

```
echo '{"Fruits":{"counter":1,"protocols":[{"id":"100","name":"lemon","category":"citrus"},{"id":"350","name":"Orange","category":"citrus" },{"id":"150","name":"lime","category":"citrus"}]}}' \
| ruby -e 'require "json";l="";ARGF.each { |x| l+=x } ; obj=JSON.parse(l) ; obj["Fruits"]["protocols"].each { |x| puts "Fruits:#{x["name"]}:#{x["category"]}" }'
```

Output:

```
Fruits:lemon:citrus
Fruits:Orange:citrus
Fruits:lime:citrus
```